# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS doesn`t work in JAVA

Tags: java, google-api, google-authentication

I tried to use [Google Speach Api](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries)

and I have big problem with authentication.

I followed this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started), and I export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, and I checked it using *echo*, and all ok.

But when I start code from first link I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:119)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:127)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:100)
at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:53)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:110)
at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.stub.GrpcSpeechStub.create(GrpcSpeechStub.java:93)
at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechSettings.createStub(SpeechSettings.java:128)
at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.<init>(SpeechClient.java:143)
at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:125)
at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:117)
at com.example.speech.QuickstartSample.main(QuickstartSample.java:58)
```

Of course I checked path in environment variable, even I get this file chmod 777, and nothing help.

anyone have similar problem?

My output for `stat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`:

```
File: /home/kruczek/Pulpit/mirthconnection-59cb32bcd531.json
Size: 2329          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 2360629     Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/ kruczek)   Gid: ( 1000/ kruczek)
Access: 2017-12-01 14:20:33.111439885 +0100
Modify: 2017-12-01 14:20:33.111439885 +0100
Change: 2017-12-01 15:24:26.476545027 +0100
Birth: -
```

but when i restart computer and i call `stat`, i have  `stat: missing operand`

my export commend `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/kruczek/Pulpit/mirthconnection-59cb32bcd531.json`
and I run project by IDE Intellij, next to `privat static void main` we have green arrow to run method.

Comment: Can you show your export command and how you run the code?

Comment: Please share output of `stat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

Comment: "but when i restart computer and i call stat, i have  stat: missing operand" - that suggests you only made sure the environment variable existed *in your current session*. It's not clear what you mean by "when I start code" - we don't know how you're running your code. If it's in the same session, it should be fine, but otherwise the environment variable won't exist.

Comment: i running code in IDE and i running it a the same session wherein i do export.

Comment: i dont set $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, but i have the same result use method from this : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/697 (last one)

Comment: Same problem here for C#. "The Application Default Credentials are not available. The environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials."

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse,
Run -> Run Configurations.. -> Environment tab

Enter GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS under Name:
Enter json path in Value:

Make sure you have not entered with quotes when enter path in Value.

Comment: This worked for me. However, just curious, why eclipse run is not picking up the enviroment variable which we have setup..